# OPmac problems with xetex/luatex, OpenType fonts and Spanish hyphenation

Tags: spanish, opmac

This is a follow of [Spanish hyphenation and UTF8 characters in plain TeX with pdfcsplain, xetex and luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266199/spanish-hyphenation-and-utf8-characters-in-plain-tex-with-pdfcsplain-xetex-and) in my attempts of use OPmac with or whitout `pdfcsplain` for Spanish documents.

In the cited question, egreg's solution to Spanish hyphenation with `xetex`/`luatex` worked like a charm for normal text,...but with respect OPmac macros I have found two problems:

1) load a OpenType font as in the egreg's MWE seem not compatible with OPmac macros as text or  `\tit Mañana` or `\sec Mañana` loss the `ñ` and print "Maana" with the default font (but it is OK in normal text).

This is the minor problem since  `\input ucode` plus `\input cs-xxxxx` (where `xxxxx` must be a TeX Gyre font) produce the correct output (This is a somewhat limited solution, but fortunately with a nice font family).

2) The most severe problem is related with the hyphenation solution, as`\uselanguage{espanol}` produce an error with `\caption/f` or `\caption/t` macros, so the PDF cannot be compiled.

Minimal not-working example to test:

```
\font\tenrm="DejaVu Serif" at 12pt  
\tenrm
\input opmac

\tit  Mañana % Missing "ñ'', without DejaVu Serif

\sec Mañana % Missing "ñ'' without DejaVu Serif 

Mañana  % No problem 

\input ucode 
\input cs-pagella  % only TeX Gyre fonts (try \input cs-charter)  

\tit  Mañana % Now OK

\sec Mañana % Now OK

\uselanguage{espanol} % Spanish hyphenation (see egreg's answer)

\caption/f Test % Error only due to \uselanguage{espanol}

\bye
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @Louie Obviosly, avoid these problems `:)`, i.e.,  how to have Spanish hyphenation activated (`\uselanguage{espanol}`) and working captions at the same time, and if possible, how to have others fonts that TeX Gyre fonts working smoothly with  `\tit` or  `\sec` macros.

Comment: When I try to compile this, I get, `Font \tenrm=DejaVu Serif at 12pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.`

Comment: Fran: I fear you may have a spaghetti of engines, formats, and macros. From  context and [the other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266199/spanish-hyphenation-and-utf8-characters-in-plain-tex-with-pdfcsplain-xetex-and) I collect you are trying to use xetex+hyplain+opmac. Is that correct? Beware that OPmac has its own Font Selection Scheme, so trying to load other fonts may break.

Comment: @Lorehead  *after you follow egreg's instructions*   comment  `\uselanguage{espanol}` to have a compilable version and  see the problem 1.  To see the problem 2,  uncomment `\uselanguage{espanol}`  and comment  `\caption/f Test`

Comment: @Louie The aim was  use opmac for Spanish texts in a natural way (writing "muñón de 20 µm" instead of  "mu\~n\'on de $\mu$m") and having the correct hyphenation. The way to reach the objective (engines, format and encodings) does not matter.

Comment: @Louie I am aware of the font selection scheme, so in absence of any other solution  I used `\input ucode\input cs-pagella` in my MNWE . The main problem is therefore (as far I have tested) that hyphenation break `\caption`.

Comment: I also tried to use OPmac with another format, but in my [limited] experience OPmac is [too much] closely tied to csplain. So I would recommend you to [activate spanish patterns](http://petr.olsak.net/csplain-e.html#patterns) and [regenerate csplain formats](http://petr.olsak.net/csplain-e.html#formatgen), following Olsak's instructions, and stick to using OPmac with csplain. After all, Olsak himself states that OPmac is _part_ of csplain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose that you need to run OPmac in standard `xetex` or `luatex` formats. They are generated using `etex.src` macros and hyphenation for all languages are preloaded. So, you needn't to re-generate format, just simply run `xetex` on command line.

The Spanish hyphenation pattern is activated in document by `\uselanguage{espanol}` in mentioned format.

OPmac uses three auto-generated words: Chapter, Table, Figure. It must know the translation of these words in selected language. But only Czech and Slovak translations are ready, because the author of OPmac isn't multilingual person(:. So, you must to set these three words in your language. And more words, if you will use `\mtext` macro (multilingual text) in your macros.

Moreover, the short-cut of used languages must be set: `es` for Spanish. OPmac sets only `en`, `cs` and `sk`. These short-cuts are set for all languages only in csplain, but you are using format from `etex.src` macros. So, you have to write this:

```
{\uselanguage{espanol}  \sxdef{lan:\the\language}{es}}
```

This is bug in OPmac documentation that this isn't mentioned there. I hope that this will be corrected. Thank you for your testing and reporting.

Finally, you can use the OTF font, but load all variants: `\tenrm`, `\tenit`, `\tenbf` and `\tenbi`. This means, you must to load whole family. Then the bold variant is used in titles. Your mistake was that bold variant was not loaded. Then the default Knuth's non-OTF font was used for titles.

OPmac uses csplain's font selection system: if the whole family `\tenrm`, `\tenit`, `\tenbf` and `\tenbi` is loaded then it is used in all desired sizes. The size of normal text in the document is set by `\typosize`.
Don't use `at12pt` clause when `\font` primitive is used.

Your example looks like:

```
\input opmac

\font\tenrm="DejaVu Serif"
\font\tenbf="DejaVu Serif/B"
\font\tenit="DejaVu Serif/I"
\font\tenbi="DejaVu Serif/IB"
\tenrm

{\uselanguage{espanol}  \sxdef{lan:\the\language}{es}}

\sdef{mt:chap:es}{Capítulo}
\sdef{mt:t:es}{Tabla}
\sdef{mt:f:es}{Figura}

\uselanguage{espanol} % Spanish hyphenation
\typosize[12/14.4]

\tit  Mañana

\sec Mañana

Mañana

\caption/f Test 

\bye
```

Process it using `xetex example` or `luatex example`.

Comment: Excellent answer. Now all seem correct, including special symbols and hyphenation. I will accept just now, but for the shake of the completeness,  it would be nice see a  similar solution for pdfcsplain.

Comment: One minor thing about your translation: babel traslate "Table" as "Cuadro".  Although at the present time almost everybody use "Tabla" for any type of table by English influence, "tabla"  in Spanish should be used for tables with numbers only  (like  the multiplication table). A "tabla" is always a "cuadro", bust rarely a "cuadro" is only a "tabla".

Comment: @Fran ad "similar solution for pdfcsplain": If you don't want to fall to the "encoding hell" then use xetex or luatex. There exists the csplain using xetex or luatex but I don't see any advantage for using it in this task. You must to re-generate format for using Spanish hyphenation and then the usage is almost the same as described above. If you want to fall to the mentioned hell, then you can use pdfcsplain (engine pdftex) and T1 encoded fonts and `\input t1code \input utf8lat1`. CSplain reports all UTF8 codes out of declared encoding. You can map them to csname and to define csname.

Comment: Note, that the section about non-Czech non-English language were added to the OPmac documantation.

Comment: At the end of day, in common documents I saw little difference between the "encoding hell"  of pdfcsplain+TeX Gyre fonts and the "xetex paradise", since most free OpenType fonts only have a little subset of uft8 symbols (a nice exception is the  >3400 glyphs of DejaVu), but I wanted to be sure of stack to the best option.  Many thanks to clarify, and overall, thanks to extent the documentation to another languages. It is nice known `\sortingdata`  before to facing the problem of  sorting a Spanish index!

Comment: Does this not work still with LuaTeX? I am getting this error `! Font \tenrm=DejaVu Serif not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> `

Comment: When `\input luafonts` is included before first usage of `\font` primitive then it does work with LuaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

OPmac was designed to work with csplain by default, so you don't need to fiddle with other formats. You may add hyphenation patterns for more languages (Spanish among others) following the instructions given [here](http://petr.olsak.net/csplain-e.html#patterns); after that, you need to regenerate the csplain format for your favourite engine as explained [here](http://petr.olsak.net/csplain-e.html#formatgen). Make sure you have installed the Spanish hyphenation patterns available [here](http://tug.org/tex-hyphen/).

Comment: Thanks. That is what I  tried first with  `pdfcsplain`,  but I made something wrong (may be `\eslang` without  `\input t1code` or forget `texhash`).  Finally I have been able to do, so that `\input opmac \input t1code \input utf8lat1 \eslang` work with the right hyphenation,  but  this way remain at least the inconvenient of some unknown symbols,  even using TeX Gyre fonts  (`\input cs-pagella`, etc.).